# Excel search and copy from more sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file.xls with three sheets.

**Sheet1**, 2 columns, 3000 rows;

- ColumnA: location_id
- ColumnB: location_label

**Sheet2**, 2 columns, 5000 rows;

- ColumnA: location_id
- ColumnB: screen_id

**Sheet3**, 2 columns, 6000 rows;

- ColumnA: screen_id
- ColumnB: screen_name

how to group data into a new **sheet4** with the following syntax (view image);

- ColumnA: Location_label
- ColumnB: screen_name

location_id get location_label name in sheet 1, location_id get screen_id value in sheet2, screen_id get screen_name value in sheet3 and in sheet4 result with location_label and screen_name.

**#EDIT QUESTION WITH USE VLOOKUP**;

I tried to use VLOOKUP but from error after the first id number 19 of sheet2...i have used this '

`=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2;Sheet1!A2:B2133;2;)`

i get

- RED
- GREEN
- YELLOW
- #N/D
- #N/D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub pair_value()

'here i tried to deconstruct the code so it is easy to follow
'this type of paring would work much better with access
'you can use this code to start
Dim h1 As Integer 'row count in sheet1
Dim h2 As Integer 'row count in sheet2
Dim h3 As Integer 'row count in sheet3
Dim h4 As Integer 'row count in sheet4
Dim ar1() As Variant
Dim ar2() As Variant
Dim ar3() As Variant
Dim ar4() As Variant
Dim pair1() As Variant

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim range3 As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'---------------------------------------------------
'This exercise would be so much easier using ACCESS
'---------------------------------------------------

'number of rows in each sheets
h1 = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
h2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
h3 = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
h4 = Worksheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'define arrays
ReDim ar1(h1, 2)
ReDim ar2(h2, 2)
ReDim ar3(h3, 2)


ReDim pair1(h2, 2)

'set range
Set range1 = Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(h1, 2))
Set range2 = Worksheets(2).Range(Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 1), Worksheets(2).Cells(h2, 2))
Set range3 = Worksheets(3).Range(Worksheets(3).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(3).Cells(h3, 2))

'load range into arrays
ar1 = range1
ar2 = range2
ar3 = range3

'associate location_label to screen_id using location_id as primary key
For i = 1 To UBound(ar2)
   
    For j = 1 To UBound(ar1)
        If ar2(i, 1) = ar1(j, 1) Then
            'load screen id + label in pair1 in pair1 array
            pair1(i, 1) = ar2(i, 2)
            pair1(i, 2) = ar1(j, 2)
            
        End If
    Next j
Next i

 
'associate location_label to screen_name using screen_id as primary key
For i = 1 To UBound(ar3)
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(pair1)
        If ar3(i, 1) = pair1(j, 1) Then
            Debug.Print j
            'past results in sheets(4)
             h4 = Worksheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
             Worksheets(4).Cells(h4 + 1, 1).Value = pair1(j, 2)
             Worksheets(4).Cells(h4 + 1, 2).Value = ar3(i, 2)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not the best with Excel and I do not fully understand what you want as an end result. But here is my guess what I think is the problem.

I suspect that in sheet 4 you type you code in A2 and use your mouse to drag the formula to the bottom of the column. If this is the case, your formula will not be exactly the same in every cell, because your matrix in the formula will change while you drag your mouse. Therefore the error #N/D

To prevent your matrix from changing while dragging your mouse you should use '$'.

So your formula would be:

> =VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2;Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2133;2;)

Possibly a tip:
I see you have the same columns in more than 1 sheet. You can put all you data in 1 sheet and then use filters to select the data you want. See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-7fbe34f4-8382-431d-942e-41e9a88f6a96) article.